# CSS gradient: simulate progress bar

Tags: html, css

[image]

Trying to simulate this progress bar using css. It has two backgrounds and one of the backgrounds should only cover a part of the bar, behind the text. The width of it should be easy to manipulate to change the %. 
I started with the a full bar, but really not sure how add the percentage part to it. Is it possible to do without absolute positioning?

```
<div class="bar">
    Progress: 60%
</div>

.bar {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;        
    background: #003458;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #003458 0%, #001727 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#003458), color-stop(100%,#001727));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #003458 0%,#001727 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #003458 0%,#001727 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #003458 0%,#001727 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #003458 0%,#001727 100%);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hMRyy/4/)

Comment: You should really do this using an inner element as the filled bar part, which makes everything a whole lot easier

Comment: @Bojangles, so how to put text on top of it then? absolute positioning?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to lighten up like your example demonstrates, overlay 2 gradients:

```
.bar {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 60%, transparent 60%),
                linear-gradient(to bottom, #003458 0%,#001727 100%);
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hMRyy/7/). (Removed the vendor prefixes, you should add them again in the final code)

---

But the problem is, how would you know how large the bar should be? You could create several classes for each value or use JavaScript for this, but of course both solutions are not good. So like others said: Use an inner element:

```
<div class="bar">
    <p>Progress: 60%</p>
    <span style="width: 60%"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #003458 0%,#001727 100%);
}

.bar > span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.bar > p {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

With that you can style the value by setting the `width` within the `<span/>`'s style attribute. Btw.: I changed the `display: table-cell` to `block` and added `line-height` to vertically center the text. This should work in this case because there is no line break. Besides that, `position: relative` does nothing on table cells.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bgkLZ/).

Comment: how about browser support?

Comment: Browsers that support gradients also support multiple backgrounds.

Comment: Here you are. That's the way I would do it.

Comment: its just like a hack what about other colors? I should add I had use this way before and its perfect. but can't include diffrent colors.

Comment: Ahm, no, it's not a hack, it's the only pure css version that works. You can change colors as you like, for the gradient and the overlay. [Here is an ugly example](http://jsfiddle.net/bgkLZ/1/).

Comment: I know I mean you should spend time to find the colors and the opacity to create that thing right?

Comment: Oh boy, just realized it was not the OP I was speaking with. Sorry! Yeah, your answer is partly correct, except: Did you see your fiddle? Check it with FF.

Comment: :-D yes you are right its not forking with latest version of FF and thats very bad cause now I don't know how to do that. btw +1 for your answer (-: